# Xamarin.Forms not centering layouts in android

Tags: layout, xamarin.forms

I have 3 labels - I want to center the second label and to fill the other space with equal sizes for the first and third label.

Instead I see there is a consideration of the string when using the LayoutOption.FillANdExpand

here is my code:

```
class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        StackLayout a = new StackLayout();
        a.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        a.Spacing = 0;
        a.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        a.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

        Label l1 = new Label { Text = "1111", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, BackgroundColor = Color.Red, };
        Label l2 = new Label { Text = "2222222222222", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray };
        Label l3 = new Label { Text = "333333333333", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, BackgroundColor = Color.Red };

        a.Children.Add(l1);
        a.Children.Add(l2);
        a.Children.Add(l3);
        Content = a;
    }
}
```

the result is this: [image]

I want the 111 and the 33333... labels to have the same size and the 2222 label to be in the center of my page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Grid` with 3 columns:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   <ColumnDefinition/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Label Text="1111" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Red" />
 <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="2222222222222" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Gray" />
 <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="33333" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Red" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

While Grid seems to work ok for that, it a little bit overhead. You can try this layout options:

```
      Label l1 = new Label { Text = "1111", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, BackgroundColor = Color.Red, };
      Label l2 = new Label { Text = "2222222222222", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray };
      Label l3 = new Label { Text = "333333333333", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, BackgroundColor = Color.Red };
```